# Validating String Characters as Numeric w/ Pascal Script (FastReport 4)

Tags: delphi, validation, pascal, fastreport, pascalscript

I'm new to Pascal and FastReport. This question can probably be answered without knowledge of FastReport. Pascal is Delphi. FastReport4. Edit: I am using pascal script.

I have a text box accepting an 8 character string as input. Each character should be numeric. I'm attempting to validate each character as numeric. I've tried using the val function...

```
Procedure Val(S : String; var R: Real; Code : Integer);
  begin
  end;

procedure thisinputOnChange(Sender: TfrxComponent);
    var
      S     : String;
      error : Integer;
      R     : Real;    
   begin

    S := thisinput.lines.text; 
   Val (S, R, error);        
     If error > 0 then
   Button2.enabled := False;       
  end;
```

I got this code online. The explanation says that the function will return an error with a code greater than zero if the character cannot be converted to an integer. Is that explanation correct? Am I misinterpreting?

Right now I am trying to set a button's enabled property to false if the validation fails. I might change that to a message. For now, I would like to get it to work by setting the button property.

I'm not sure if I should be using the onChange event or another event. I'm also not sure if I need to send the input to the val function in a loop. Like I said, I'm just learning how to use this function.

I am able to validate the length. This code works...

```
  procedure thisinputOnChange(Sender: TfrxComponent);

  begin

     if length(thisinput.lines.text) = 8 then          
        Button2.enabled := True;

  end;
```

Any suggestions? Should I use the val function or something else? Let me know if I need to provide more info. I might not be able to check back until later, though.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Delphi or Lazarus? Also, `Val` is a runtime library function (in the `System` unit in both Delphi and Lazarus; it's not something you implement yourself. (Your implementation does nothing at all, BTW.) Shouldn't you be validating the data before it ever gets to FastReport? FR is a reporting engine; I'm not sure why you'd expect to be using it to get input or trying to validate things there.

Comment: It is Delphi. I just edited my post to include that. The user inputs the data in a textbox. That data is used to query a database for a report. It cannot be validated before it gets to FastReport. Going by your response, I cannot use the val function for this. Thanks for letting me know that. I'll have to find another way.

Comment: Your method looks odd: `procedure thisinputOnChange(Sender: TfrxComponent);`.  Is that a form method, ie should it really be `procedure **TForm1.**thisinputOnChange(Sender: TfrxComponent);`? Can you show your full/real code please? The mixup with Delphi or Pascal is confusing too - are you using Delphi (and which version) or Turbo Pascal or Lazarus / Free Pascal? Finally, why are you defining your own empty version of `Val`? As Ken says it won't do anything!  You should use the real `Val` ("Going by your response, I cannot use the Val function" is *not* what Ken meant.)

Comment: I should have made it clear that I know that the code I posted is incomplete. I thought I had to add some code to the val procedure and then call it. I just found out that we are using pascal script. I don't believe I can use val at all with that.

Comment: I just updated my original post to indicate I am using pascal script. That changes things as far as what I can use. Thanks to all for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

[`procedure System.Val(S: String; var V; var Code: Integer);`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Val) is an intrinsic procedure. You don't need to define it yourself.

You can use it to validate your string as an integer.

```
var
  myInt,error : Integer;
...
Val(s,myInt,error);
Button2.Enabled := (error = 0); // ok if error is zero
```

Should the string be invalid, error points to the first invalid character in the string.

---

As an option, you could also use

[`function SysUtils.TryStrToInt(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt)

```
Button2.Enabled := TryStrToInt(s,myInt); // ok if true
```

---

Edit:
An example of using `Val()` with pascal script can be found here:
[`Pascal script examples`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Pascal_Script_Examples).

```
procedure MyVal(const s: string; var n, z: Integer);
begin
  Val(s, n, z);
end;
```

Register the procedure in the `OnCompile` method when registering your scripts:

```
Sender.AddFunction(@MyVal, 'procedure Val(const s: string; var n, z: Integer)');
```

---

By looking into the document `FastScript 1.9
Scripting library` there is an integer validation function

```
function ValidInt(cInt: String): Boolean
```

To get access to this function, follow guidlines in the document (P21):

> "To get an access to these functions, pass the fsGlobalUnit reference to the TfsScript.Parent property."

Note: I could not add a link to the document, but a quick search on google should get you there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I apologize for not providing all of the correct information. I just found out that we are using pascal script. I won't go into details, but it can be difficult to get that information where I am working. The Val function is undefined. I believe SysUtils.TryStrToInt is also unavailable. I hope this answer is useful to someone else.

Comment: @user2525015, see my added link and example how to register `Val()` procedure in pascal script.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I even have access to the OnCompile method with FastReport. The report has OnRunDialogs, OnStartReport, and a few other events. I am trying to find out if I do have a way to register procedures with our setup.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with `FastReport` utilization of scripts. But my latest addition seems to reveal a built-in function you could use.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the Delphi version. Since Delphi 2009 you can set the NumbersOnly property of a TEdit to restrict the input to digits.

Comment: I'm attempting to find out the Delphi version now. It's embedded in the software we are using. There is not help or about menu to specify the version. I have to find that info from a remote location.